# Better way to a front-end and back-end developing

Tags: backbone.js, frameworks, ember.js, frontend, backend

I'm starting a project and I'm not sure about **what technology to use on the back-end and front-end sides**. The project needs to generate charts and a lot of statistics so I have been surfing on the site and I think that the best way to front-end is Backbone.js or Ember.js, is it?

On the other hand I've to decide the server part. I'm an old school developer...Php. I need to develope an API that reads de ddbb and provide the information to the front-end side. I don't know what is the best way to develope a system that let final user to choose a date interval to view their statistics (like Google Analytics, Square, etc.). Maybe Ruby? Symfony as well?

Thx! =)

Comment: the best tools are those that you know, you feel comfortable using and that get you the job done. this is obviously very subjective and down to personal preferences.

Comment: Yes of course that I could do the work with php :) But I'd like to know about other options that could be better. I think that nowadays a lot of things about web are changing and seems like javascript is killin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in your same situation months ago and I decided to go for Backbone. The main reason is that it's more used and so it's easier to get help and find good tutorials, plus it's not much opinionated so I think you can learn more while develping and also you can shape your app to fit better your needs. Anyway I didn't tried in deep Ember or Angular so take my opinion with care. For the server side part I've always worked with PHP too, I tried Ruby and I think it's a better support for a webapp but I ended use PHP anyway cause of my company's needs. You can do a good job with PHP too, but I suggest to use frameworks like Silex, Slim or Laravel that are better suited to put up a REST api which you will need if you want to use Backbone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering if php could be the better way to do a API. I always use CodeIgniter or Cakephp, but I see that Silex, Slim and Laravel are lighter than the frameworks that I use. If I can use php for the back-end is better for me. And for the front-end I'm going to play with backbone and see how it works :)